# Google Play internal test no waiting

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I just set internal test and it shows I can be waiting up to 48hours.
Is there any way to publish app only for selected users (mails) without waiting that long?
Even after first publish it should take a few hours for app to be available to testers.
Maybe some mode in which app is available to selected users immediately?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set up a closed test:

With a closed test, you can create a list of testers by email address. You can create a total of 200 lists, and each list can have up to 2,000 users. You can create up to 50 lists per track.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Open Closed test: manage testers by email address TAB to see the instructions.

2. You can use Crashlytics which also works by sending the app to testers invited by email and you get automatic bug tracker which is nice: (This is for debug version of the app)

https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/features

Comment: I want it to be available immediately. As I know in closed test I still have to wait some time just like in internal test.